# How to add meta description correct way

Tags: headers

i need help on my meta description. I would like it to start like this

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt(), true ); ?>" />
```

Then the next like to be for homepage where i input my own text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add a meta description to your WordPress website, follow these steps:

1. Install and activate an SEO plugin such as Yoast SEO, All in One SEO Pack, or Rank Math.
2. Once the plugin is installed, go to your WordPress dashboard and navigate to the page or post that you want to add a meta description to.
3. Scroll down to the section labeled "Yoast SEO" (if you're using Yoast SEO) or "Rank Math SEO" (if you're using Rank Math).
4. In the meta box, you will see a field labeled "Meta Description" or "Snippet Preview". This is where you can add your meta description.
5. Write a compelling and accurate description of your page or post that is under 160 characters long. This description should accurately summarize the content on the page and encourage users to click through to your website.
6. Save your changes and publish your page or post.

It's important to note that adding a meta description is just one part of optimizing your website for search engines. You should also focus on creating high-quality content, using appropriate keywords, and ensuring that your website is user-friendly and easy to navigate. Additionally, make sure to optimize your website's title tags, headings, images, and URLs to help improve your website's search engine rankings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to add the meta description without using plugin, you can start with this code:

```
function wpse_meta_description() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        $des_post = strip_tags( $post->post_content );
        $des_post = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );
        $des_post = str_replace( array("\n", "\r", "\t"), ' ', $des_post );
        $des_post = mb_substr( $des_post, 0, 300, 'utf8' );
        echo '<meta name="description" content="' . $des_post . '" />' . "\n";
    }
    if ( is_home() ) {
        echo '<meta name="description" content="' . get_bloginfo( "description" ) . '" />' . "\n";
    }
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $des_cat = strip_tags( category_description() );
        echo '<meta name="description" content="' . $des_cat . '" />' . "\n";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_meta_description');
```

[Credit [GretaThemes](https://gretathemes.com/seo-add-meta-tags-without-plugins/)]

This code adds meta description to singular pages, homepage and categories. However, there are other pages in WordPress that you need to handle as well, such as author, date and search pages. You might also want to add meta description manually for some specific pages. Because of these reasons, using a SEO plugin is better. If you want to keep your site lightweight, then you can choose [Slim SEO](https://wpslimseo.com) or [The SEO Framework](https://theseoframework.com/), the best lightweight plugins for WordPress at the moment.